# Akka ask work around the ignore of the sender

Tags: java, scala, akka, future

I am trying to store the sender of a certain message so I can check in the future if it was the same sender that has sent the operation as before. Now this is not working and I read it is because the Akka ask ignores the actual sender and makes its own temporary actor which is used as sender until the future is resolved. Is there a way to work around this problem so you can access the real sender of the message without using the tell operation?

Answer (score 3):

Put the `ActorRef` of the sending actor in the message. You will have to do this when you move to Akka Typed so it is good practice not to rely on `sender()` even when using Akka Classic.

Answer (score 2):

There's no workaround that doesn't use `tell`, because there's nothing in Akka that doesn't use `tell` (the Akka provided ask pattern is a pattern based on `tell`s).

The ask pattern implementation has to use a temporary actor in order to encapsulate the timeout logic and not leak that functionality into the actor requesting the ask.

This leaves two options for giving the receiver access to the "real" sender:

1. You can add an `onBehalfOf` `ActorRef` field to the message you're sending as an ask (you may want to make it optional for the case where the ask is originating outside of an actor whose `receive` you control), and have the receiver use that instead of `sender`.
2. You can implement the ask pattern yourself in the sending actor: this is just a `tell`, scheduling a message to the sending actor after the timeout expires, and then having some means in your message protocol (the requests and responses) to determine which ask a given response is for).

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and as Tim and Levi point out there is no clean way to do this. Even in akka typed the is no straight forward way. Because while the sender is explicit it is very common to require adaptors to map between protocols of different actors.

If you want to track the source of your messages in an actor, I suggest you make that explicit in the protocol of the actor and use an opaque type to represent the source in messages where it is tracked. Then it is obvious to the client what you are doing. It also makes bugs harder where one ActorRef to reply to and one used as the source get mixed up.

Overloading the ActorRef for this could lead to confusion esp after moving to akka typed, where you would need one ActorRef as sender and another as source/identity.

Here is an actor typed example (I didn't have a classic akka project to hand).

```
/** Opaque value to represent a unique actor as the source of messages */
final case class ActorSource private (ref: ActorRef[_])

object ActorSource {
  /** Constructing ActorSource from the context ensures actor is who it says it is */
  def apply[T](context: ActorContext[T]): ActorSource = new ActorSource(context.self)
}

final case class TrackedMessage(data: String, source: ActorSource, sender[ActorRef[ReplyProtocol]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `ExplicitAskSupport` trait which adds additional overloads of the `ask` method which allows you to pass the reference of the actor which gets implicitly created by akka when using the ask pattern:

```
def ask(message: ActorRef => Any)(implicit timeout: Timeout, sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Future[Any]
```